# Google Auth2 Api refresh token limit

Tags: refresh, token

I think I have gone over the limit of 25 refresh tokens while testing. When I use my current refresh token to try and get a new access token I get  [error] => internal_failure. How can I tell if I have gone over the limit and what can I do if I have?

Comment: I don't think you will get internal_failure if you reach the limit, but rather more clear explanation which states that you have reached the limit. look for headers/credentials are correct ... etc etc...

Comment: It's now saying [error] => invalid_grant